# Angular calling a function from the view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am mostly looking for some 'best practice' advice here.

I have a view which contains a table of data that is pulled from an API. This data needs to be sorted with a call to the API by clicking on a column heading. Imagine clicking the column firstName and the data sorts alphabetically, and clicking again will sort the same column descending.

The data is provided via a service through the controller initially when the user logs in. This data is presented in the table.

I then have the functionality to sort the data via the clicked heading as mentioned above.

By putting this functionality into a Directive with a controller function, whereby the clicked column calls a function within that directive, the functionality fires, and a console.log will reveal that the data has been returned correctly sorted, however the view doesn't update to reveal the reordered data.

I have fiddled about for a long time with `watch`, `apply` & two way databinding via the `scope` option, but to no avail.

If I put this same functionality into the controller itself the reorder and data refresh works immediately.

I am really trying to remove this functionality to be separated into a directive as, from my understanding, view interactions should be dealt with by directives to be 'the angular way' but I just cannot get it to work like this.

Any well explained (simply) advice would be much appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: This community is not intended for giving advices, please take a look on how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create a directive to handle the sorting, you can use `ng-click="yourController.sortTheData()"`

If you think about it, your intention is not really to manipulate the view layer. Your intention is to order the list. Angular will handle re-drawing the data.

However, if you still desire to use a directive to perform the sorting, here is an example on Plunker that I think mirrors what you were trying to achieve. 
https://plnkr.co/edit/ILM26qF1BOJvSwsOnLoi?p=preview

```js
angular.module('app', [])

.service('dataService', function($filter) {
  var data = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Apple'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Boy'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Cat'
  }, {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Dog'
  }, {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Elephant'
  }];
  var ascending = true;
  this.getData = function() {
    return data;
  }
  this.sortData = function(propertyName) {
    ascending = !ascending;
    var direction = ascending ? '+' : '-';

    var sortedData = $filter('orderBy')(data, direction + propertyName);
    //since everyone is referencing data by reference, we need to empty the array and fill it with the new data
    data.splice(0, data.length);
    Array.prototype.push.apply(data, sortedData);
    return data;
  }

}).controller('MyController', function($filter, dataService) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.data = dataService.getData();
  vm.ascending = true;
  vm.sortOutsideDirective = function() {
    vm.data = dataService.sortData('name');
  }
}).directive('sortable', function(dataService) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      propertyName: '=sortable'
    },
    link: function($scope, element, attributes) {
      element.on('click', function() {
        dataService.sortData($scope.propertyName);
        $scope.$apply()
      })
    }
  };
})
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

th{
  cursor:pointer;
  }
th, td{
  padding:20px;
  border:1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.0" data-semver="1.5.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MyController as vm">
  <button ng-click="vm.sortOutsideDirective()">Sort outside by name</button>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th sortable="'id'">ID</th>
      <th sortable="'name'">Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in vm.data">
      <td>{{item.id}}</td>
      <td>{{item.name}}</td>
    </tr>
  <sorter data="vm.data" direction="vm.direction"></sorter>
</body> 

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @TwitchBronBron. Where I had used it in the controller I was indeed calling the function with ng-click from the view, but with trying to put as much emphasis as possible in separating concerns I wanted to abstract as much of the logic away from the controller as possible. But what you say is true about the view manipulation. I will use the controller approach. Thank you for the excellent code example as well. Much appreciated!